# RegexValidator is not allowing 0-9 in CharField

Tags: python, regex, django

I am wanting to allow *only* characters 0-9 for all characters entered into a Django `CharField`.

When I use `RegexValidator()` with `regex = r'[^0-9]'`. I can enter everything *but* 0-9 in the field.  Actually, it will allow me to enter a strings like `"word"`, `"a4523"`, `"!#$%#^%"`, and `"5432bc"`, but *not* `"4523"`.

If I take out the `^` and set `regex = r'[0-9]'` (see code below) then I *can* enter `"4523"`, `"5432bc"`, and `"a4523"` but *not* `"word"` or `"!#$%#^%"`.

Removing the `^` seems to get me in the right direction, but not the full way.  I do not want to use a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` because I want to treat the numeric input as a string.

```
class Number(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length=14,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                r'[0-9]',
                'Only 0-9 are allowed.',
                'Invalid Number'
            ),
            MinLengthValidator(4),
            MaxLengthValidator(14),
        ],
    )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression `[^0-9]` means to match a non-digit anywhere in the string. You probably meant to start with `^[0-9]`, which requires a digit at the start of the string. For a complete solution, I think you want `^[0-9]*$`, which requires all characters in the string to be digits.

Comment: Is blank allowed? ie, `*` (0 or more) vs `+` (1 or more). Also: `^\d+$`

Comment: @Hamish, there are other validators being applied to constrain the length of the input. OP apparently wants between 4 and 14 characters. In this context there's no need to encode that in the regex, though. Simplicity seems good here.

Comment: Blank is not allowed.  Though in one of the fields I want a '+' to only be allowed at the front of a string of numbers i.e. '+323' should be allowed, but the '+' is not required.

Comment: With a leading plus sign the regular expression would look like this: `r'^\+?[\d]*'`